# glassfish applet doesn't run on server

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, glassfish

I created a dynamic web project (week8) and simple HelloWorldApplet.I use eclipse and glassfish 4.0.when i try to run on server(r-click), server starts but browser

```
(http://localhost:8080/week8/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldApplet.java
```

gives this error:
"HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0"
I've googled all day long, couldn't find an answer.thanks 
folder structure is:
week8
 jax-ws webservices
 deployment descriptor: week8
 javaresoures
  src
   HelloWorldApplet.java
  libraries
 build
 webcontent
  meta-inf
  web-inf

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to access applet like this, add following HTML to your page

```
<applet code = 'HelloWorldApplet' 
    archive = '/public/path/to/your/jar/file.jar'
    width = 300
    height = 300>
</applet>
```

- [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

Comment: it works like you suggested, but i need to run within eclipse on glass fish server. i watched a few videos on youtube, right-click on java file and selecting run on server works, but not mine.thanks

Comment: You can launch your *web-app* within eclipse by right click > run on server and then your page can serve html which has this `<applet>` and then you can browse it to load applet on client jre

Comment: right click>run-on server gives this error: "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found type Status report messageNot Found descriptionThe requested resource is not available. GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0"

Comment: that means your app deployment was unsuccessful, please refer to log and fix it, this is no longer related to your main question, if this answer has been asnwered you can mark it as accepted/upvote and create new question with all the details it needs to fix deployment issue

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost:8080/week8/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldApplet.java
```

There are several problems with that:

1. It is the class (`HelloWorldApplet.class`) that needs loading, not the Java source file from which it was made.
2. Resource under `WEB-INF` are not available to the general browsing public (or the client side JVM).  The class needs to be loaded somewhere in the server such that if you put the address in the browser address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the server would provide it (usually by offering to save it somewhere).